# How to design a single site for two target markets

Tags: page-layout, layout

I have a client that operates an electronics recycling/disposition company. Broadly speaking, they have two target markets and I would like to figure out how to structure the site so that I can target both with minimal confusion. I will explain the issue in more detail below.

The first market is small to medium sized businesses. The clients in this market typically have used electronics (computers, TVs, printers, phones, batteries, etc.) that they want to dispose of as cheaply as possible. My client serves these clients by picking up the electronics for free and breaking them down for parts. The main needs for this type of client are convenience (pick up is easy to arrange and does not require any involvement of their employees) and low cost. Essentially, they want to get rid of their electronics quickly and at minimal expense.

The second market is larger corporate clients. The clients in this market typically require secure data destruction, and asset management and disposition (wiping computers/phones, refurbishing them and re-selling them). The main needs for this type of client are ensuring that their data is safely destroyed (secure data destruction) and that their assets provide them with a small return when they are re-sold (asset management and disposition).

There might be some overlap between these markets (a small company who needs their hard drives securely destroyed) but for the most part, the service offerings are clearly delineated by target market.

My main concern is ensuring that clients that arrive from organic search understand what service is targeted towards them. For instance, I do not want a small business client to see data destruction services and think that is overkill for them. On the other hand, I do not want a large corporate client seeing that their electronics are being picked up for free and immediately start wondering what is going to happen to their secure data.

Any help in figuring out how to best structure both the home page and other pages of the site would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't feel like this is a fair decision to put this on hold. I understand that there is a specific example given but the idea of a general design problem is highlighted by the fact that I want to know, generally speaking, how to design a site for two target markets.

Answer (score 2):

Two tabs one saying "for small to medium sized businesses" and another with "larger corporate clients". I design for a real estate website so we target agents, home buyers, advertisers and investors. We have a different section for each.

Just make sure you make each section very clear about whether it's the right page for them eg have a clear CTA saying on the corporate page that says "Are you a small to medium sized business"?

Research different companies and see how they deal with it.

Comment: What do you mean by tabs? That could mean a few different things. Are you able to post an example of a real estate site that you think does this well?

Comment: I meant tabs as a general term, but it could be the menu in the nav bar or separate content boxes on the homepage. I'm not sure if Trulia does it well, but as an example see how they have "for professionals" at the top? Also see how they have the 3 content boxes below the header, I would use something like that but using 2 - one asking "are you a small to medium business" and the other "are you a large corporate"? I'm not saying this would work, but that's the first thing I would try. Just make sure if your visitors end up in the wrong section, there is always a clear and easy way out.